# Java error cannot find symbol class Scanner.using jdk 6

Tags: java

```
import java.util.scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FirstHomeJavaApplet{

public static void main(String[] args){

int num1=2;

int num2=2;

int sum;

sum=num1+num2;

System.out.println("My first home practice of java applet"); 

 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, num1 + "+" + num2 + " = " + sum, "Result of Addition", 

JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

}

}
```

This is my code but it is giving 1 error.I am using jdk 6 to run this applet.

The error is :cannot find symbol

```
symbol:class scanner

location:package java.util

import.java.util.scanner;

               ^
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scanner should start with a capital S :)

Answer (score 0):

By convention, Java classes start with capital letters.  So it should be `Scanner` throughout.  E.g.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Answer (score 0):

The class is called [java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) (with a capital S).

Answer (score 0):

See that your class name starts with a Capital letter java.util.Scanner; instead of java.util.scanner;

Answer (score 0):

Because the class name is Scanner not scanner.